# ASP.NET MVC @Url.Action redirects only to controller, not to action

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am learning the basis of HTML, Bootstrap & JavaScript. I want to use bootstrap nav class for navigation. The first problem: bootstrap doesn't work in shared view `_Layout.cshtml` and buttons look like:

[image]

But the content of `index.cshtml` looks OK.
The second problem: when I click on Messages, it redirects me only to controller ../User, not to its action ../User/Index. I have no idea why it does not work.

Below my `_Layout.cshtml` code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/lib/twitter-bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li role="navigation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li role="navigation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
            <li role="navigation"><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "User")">Messages</a></li>
        </ul>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For first problem, Try to change from

```
<link href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

To:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

For second problem, try to change from `@Url.Action("Index", "User")` to `@Url.Action("User")`

You have to make sure that your controller naming is correct. Otherwise, we may need your UserController sample code for further assist

Comment: When I changed link href.. to link rel.. nothing happened. I also changed  @Url.Action("Index", "User") to @Url.Action("User") and now it redirects me to ../Home/User

Answer (score 0):

Everything works fine when I manually go to ../User/Index view.
Here is the part of `UserController.cs` class:

```
public class UserController : Controller
   {
       private readonly DietDbContext _dbContext;
       private readonly IMapper _mapper;

       public UserController(DietDbContext dbContext, IMapper mapper)
       {
           _dbContext = dbContext;
           _mapper = mapper;
       }

       public ActionResult Index()
       {
           return View(_dbContext.Users.ToList());
       }
```